# EXTJS Creating sub string for a column value (returning the back half)

Tags: extjs, substring

I am looking to return a substring for a column in a grid. The values passed in are html links, I would like to take return everything in the string past the last '/'

```
{
  header: 'Site',
  width: 22,
  sortable: true,
  hideable:false, 
  renderer: function(v) {
    return Ext.util.Format.substr(v, 1, 8); // I know this is how you do the substring, but how do you get the final . and the last array position?
  },
  dataIndex: 'site'
}
```

Looking for something like this:

```
renderer: function(v) {
    return Ext.util.Format.substr(v, v.lastIndexOf("/"), v.end()); 
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
renderer: function (value, meta) {
                return Ext.util.Format.substr(value, value.lastIndexOf("/")+1, value.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to use:

```
renderer: v => v.split('/').pop()
```

Comment: Since I needed more in renderer I kept my solution, however your's worked perfectly.  

renderer: function (value, meta) {
                meta.style = "color:blue;";
...